# Flutter tabs not properly underlined

Tags: flutter

I have the following tabs:

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  int _currentIndex = 0;

  final List<Widget> _children = [
    DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              flexibleSpace: SafeArea(
                child: TabBar(
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.listAlt)),
                    Tab(icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.map)),
                    Tab(icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.cog))
                  ],
                )
              )
            ),
            body: TabBarView(
              children: [
                TrendingList(),
                TrendingMap(),
                TrendingConfiguration()
              ],
            )
        )
    ),
    PlaceholderWidget(Colors.white),
    PlaceholderWidget(Colors.deepOrange),
    PlaceholderWidget(Colors.green)
  ];

  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _children[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: onTabTapped,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.chartLine),
            title: new Text('Trending'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.glasses),
            title: new Text('Watchlist'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.user),
              title: Text('Me'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.bell),
            title: Text('Notifications'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This results in the following:

[image]

Why are my tabs not properly underlined and how do I fix it?
I don't want a title.

Comment: i have answered this question may have a look at it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62305702/13699785

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Right place to use `TabBar` is `bottom` of `AppBar`.

As mentioned in Docs - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html

> The bottom is usually used for a TabBar.

Code:

```
child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Dummy'),
              bottom: TabBar(
                tabs: [
                  Tab(icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.listAlt)),
                  Tab(icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.map)),
                  Tab(icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.cog))
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Code: With no title.

```
appBar: AppBar(
              flexibleSpace: SafeArea(
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: kToolbarHeight,
                  child: TabBar(
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.listAlt)),
                      Tab(icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.map)),
                      Tab(icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.cog))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              bottom: PreferredSize(child: SizedBox(), preferredSize: Size.zero),
            ),
```

[image]

Comment: Meanwhile I found a plugin with nice bubble tabs. As mentioned, I didn't want the title, and the empty navbar above will serve a different purpose. What this code achieved was that an empty (double) appbar appeared.

Comment: @Trace - Updated answer.